# showing multiple portrait view screens in one single screen in landscape view in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, mobile, tablet, landscape-portrait

I am making a restaurant app foe mobile and tablet in flutter. The problem I am facing is in mobile view I have these screens(burger,sandwich,...category screen LHS), (the product screen in MIDDLE), and (the cart screen in RHS). But in Tablet screen I have the these screens as one screen. so how can i show all these screens in one screen in landscape view (for tablet).

Any help or guidance is appreciated!!! Thank you

[image]

Comment: there's a new dependency called `flutter_adaptive_scaffold` but you can only set up the secondary screen initially which can be an issue if you tap on an item on the first screen and want the second screen to take affect which is why this isn't an answer. any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the parent widget with OrientationBuilder
This gives you access to set conditions base on the screen Orientation.

```
OrientationBuilder(
   builder: (context, orientation) {
    return GridView.count(
     crossAxisCount: orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 2 : 3,
   );
  },
);
```